# Grafana image renderer plugin not working- retuns blank image

Tags: grafana

I am using Grafana image renderer as remote service deployed using kubernetes when click on 'Direct link rendered image' Returns blank image
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

issues solved when configured the values as follows

```yaml
- name: GF_RENDERING_SERVER_URL
  value: http://img-renderer-plugin-service:8081/render        
- name: GF_RENDERING_CALLBACK_URL
  value: https://grafana-domain/
```